# LIBSODIUM decrypt data inside mysql query like did with AES_DECRYPT

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption, libsodium

I have some sql querys where im selecting rows near to the users location.
With AES_DECRYPT i could do inside the query:

```
AES_DECRYPT(lat, :key)
```

I need the decrypted value inside the query to:
1. order them 
2. delimit entrys in a given area
3. and similar things for other querys

A short example of one query:

```
SELECT something,
(
    6371 * acos( cos( radians(".$userdatafromdbfetchedbefore['lat'].") ) * cos( radians( AES_DECRYPT(lat, :key) ) ) * cos( radians( AES_DECRYPT(lng, :key) ) - radians(".$userdatafromdbfetchedbefore['lng'].") ) + sin( radians(".$userdatafromdbfetchedbefore['lat'].") ) * sin(radians( AES_DECRYPT(lat, :key))) )
) AS distance
FROM 
    table
HAVING 
    distance <= ".$userdatafromdbfetchedbefore['maxrange']."
ORDER BY 
    e.orderdate 
DESC,
    distance  
ASC
LIMIT
    ".$start.", ".$offset."
```

I can't select all rows on a different query and manipulate the result with php, that would be very ineffiecient with 100k + rows while the rows near the user might be only ~100.

Its very important for me to keep location data encrypted, i did not start my project because of unsecure encryption until now.

Now my question is how i can do the same thing with newly php implemented Libsodium ?

I couldnt find one example that would work. I just found a example with blind index where you can find a value if you encrypt the search term same like the stored one, but that isnt helpful in my case because i need to get the value to run that through the distance formula inside the same query.

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Libsodium isn't built into MySQL. Long answer: You can use something like [ciphersweet](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet) to side-step this limitation (and get better security at the same time).

Comment: @ScottArciszewski thank you for your answer, i couldnt find a fitting example with ciphersweet according to my problem. Could you share me one ? It looks like that this libary can do blindindex searches same as i found here: https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql , but i have to get the decrypted value already inside the query. In the example above "radians(lat)"  there i need the real value like "52.5200°" else the calculation wont work with.

Comment: I posted a full answer since it was a bit long for a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Libsodium isn't built into MySQL, so you can't just call something equivalent to `AES_ENCRYPT()` from within a MySQL query and get the results you expect.

However, an alternate approach is to use a library like [CipherSweet](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet), which provides searchable authenticated encryption. Make sure you understand [its features](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/#at-a-glance) and [limitations](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/php#understanding-ciphersweets-features-and-limitations) before deciding to use it.

```
<?php
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\CipherSweet;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedRow;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Transformation\AlphaCharactersOnly;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Transformation\FirstCharacter;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Transformation\Lowercase;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Backend\FIPSCrypto;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\KeyProvider\StringProvider;

$provider = new StringProvider(
    // Example key, chosen randomly, hex-encoded:
    'a981d3894b5884f6965baea64a09bb5b4b59c10e857008fc814923cf2f2de558'
);
$engine = new CipherSweet($provider, new FIPSCrypto());

/** @var CipherSweet $engine */
$row = (new EncryptedRow($engine, 'contacts'))
    ->addTextField('first_name')
    ->addTextField('last_name')
    ->addFloatField('latitude')
    ->addFloatField('longitude');

// Notice the ->addRowTransform() method:
$row->addCompoundIndex(
    $row->createCompoundIndex(
        'contact_first_init_last_name',
        ['first_name', 'last_name'],
        64, // 64 bits = 8 bytes
        true
    )
        ->addTransform('first_name', new AlphaCharactersOnly())
        ->addTransform('first_name', new Lowercase())
        ->addTransform('first_name', new FirstCharacter())
        ->addTransform('last_name', new AlphaCharactersOnly())
        ->addTransform('last_name', new Lowercase())
);

$prepared = $row->prepareRowForStorage([
    'first_name' => 'Jane',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'latitude' => 52.52,
    'longitude' => -33.106,
    'extraneous' => true
]);

var_dump($prepared);
```

You should see something similar to this. The values in the `[0]` will change, but the values in `[1]` will not. This is becuase `[0]` contains the row data with (some fields encrypted). `[1]` only contains blind indexes (usable later in SELECT queries).

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(141) "fips:nrtzoaxvPIOA7jPskWVwJmC0q8WJqrsnqjPh3ifNPsRd2TAx6OwTDfSiMVCXSsSRNQb_nxJlW7TbAtf5UvQRWWKTGhk_kXxpZKdnTrpjbmxi0IgstSrZ126Qz6E0_lvjew0Ygw=="
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(137) "fips:98f5CLB24w0zSqCGPR0D2oq9wQvUwzxo_byAp6mKgMgoJkUHZX1oTtk4Cm8FXI7fsUI8HOG5sKQFGRn6cXMw1EOMGgpXZqiXEDb3jxEbg9s95d4g2NeVd4xs2tmX0xlZ0nSM"
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(145) "fips:d3TVGfnRFlvWxbfihgHqjpXlXU3HtkCAHzM0-4f1l5dAeQf2Vk5RDDVOGMQNM09r0O4UOAub6QTyHGezQ0bWKQ5omqoYCTBJE0Uf_2DSPfO7U4dG74phaP04iFgqpJ8G41q54Kv5t54="
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(145) "fips:IcnUnBZZOxJPYXk-F3v12O_krNb9JsexljiV4gJzgctTpxLFm7ql0tJRF7xP3wLrUtd1VyfYBf75ot7iOSIIIFqsuyKZQdI9UyKbqd87RTMsHbHgPouxgZBg1urlqpuWqbOYEFGiti4="
    ["extraneous"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["contact_first_init_last_name"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(13) "w6dsrxbathjze"
      ["value"]=>
      string(16) "546b1ffd1f83c37a"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the floating point fields will always produce a fixed-length output, even if the inputs have varying levels of precision. This is done intentionally to prevent attackers from learning information from ciphertext length.

If you select [`ModernCrypto` instead of `FIPSCrypto`](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/php/setup#select-your-backend), all of the above will be done with libsodium. The exact encryption used by each is [documented here](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/internals/encryption), if anyone is curious.

---

Note that you'll have to do your own calculations of the decrypted values in PHP rather than SQL.

After all, the whole point of encrypting data before storing it in a database is to hide it from the database server (and any attackers who could have compromised said server).

Comment: Why did you choose 64 bits in the example ?

Comment: No reason, totally arbitrary.

But you should be less lazy in production code: https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/security#blind-index-information-leaks

Comment: I didn't understand the blind index planner. In the example given you chose a 4 digit number witch has 10000 posibilities. What if i choose a 30 characters text?

Comment: Do you have an examples of decrypting the date?